# Is direct reported speech more common in Turkish than indirect reported speech?

Tags: grammar, turkish, speech-synthesis

Working in subtitles production, I have noticed direct reported speech is very common in Turkish TV shows dialogs. In Hebrew, my target language - and I thinks in English, as well - it is more common to use indirect reported speech in conversation, and using direct reported speech serves other purposes, such as theatrics, stressing a point, etc. I have also noticed there are no quotation marks (but I am not sure whether it is due to different punctuation system, or sloppy transcription).

In the following script excerpt, for example, you can see direct reported speech (sans quotation marks). In Hebrew, in the same linguistic register, indirect reported speech would probably be the natural choice:

**Ya Hayri Nalan Hanıma gittiğinde kadın dediyse ki karını boşa? Karını boşamazsan bir daha yüzümü göremezsin dediyse? Karını boşa gel, burda beraber yaşayalım, gül gibi geçinip gidelim dediyse? Abla ben ne yapacağım? Getirip önüme kağıtları koyarsa, boşanalım derse ben ne yapacağım?**

Am I right thinking direct reported speech is far more common in Turkish than indirect reported speech? Is it more common in *some* registers but never in others? And is the lack of quotation marks standard?

Thank you! :)

Comment: It looks like answering your question implies conducting a substantial statistical analysis of the corpus of Turkish texts. Without it every opinion's going to be too subjective.

Comment: Not necessarily.  I am not familiar with Turkish grammar, so for me to concur decisively on the matter would be subjective (and foolish), but I guess Turkish linguists may offer a concrete, objective answer. If you are familiar with Turkish, I would appreciate your input.